# Instantiating a @autowired bean inside @postconstruct method inside controller, spring

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I want to call a common service for all the controllers to get a commmon ModelAndView object with some common objects inside it.

So I created a superclass for all the controllers- BaseController, and I am initiating the common model object inside the constructor of BaseController by calling the a method, initCommonData which uses a @Autowired bean CommonDataService, which is not present at the construction time of object and returns `null`, so what I should do to get @autowired dependency inside constructor.

FYI - I am using this common servie and common data to get some commod data which will be used on each jsp in header and footer of the site.
So if there is some another way of doing this without calling the common service in each controller method, in each controller please suggest.
Here is my code -
BaseController

```
@Controller
public class BaseController {

@Autowired
private CommonDataService commonDataService;

protected ModelAndView model; 

public BaseController() {
    this.initCommonData();
}

public void initCommonData(){
    this.model = new ModelAndView();
    this.model.addObject("headerData",commonDataService.getHeaderData());
    this.model.addObject("footerData",commonDataService.getFooterData());
}
```

subclass controller -

```
@Controller
public class HomeController extends BaseController {

@Autowired
CategoryService categoryService;

@Autowired
CompanyService companyService;

@RequestMapping(value = { "", "/", "home" })
public ModelAndView homePage() {
    model.setViewName("home");
    .
    .
    .
    model.addObject("name", value);
    model.addObject("name2", value2);
    return model;
}
```

CommonServiceClass -

```
@Service
public class CommonDataService {

@Autowired
CompanyService companyService;

@Autowired
CategoryService categoryService;

@Cacheable
public List<Category> getHeaderData(){
    return categoryService.getTopCategoryList();
}

@Cacheable
public List<Company> getFooterData(){
    return companyService.getTopCompanyList();
}
```

Please suggest if there is any other good way of doing this, getting common data from server to jsp.

Comment: You mention `@PostConstruct` in your title, which is one answer to your trouble, so why didn't you use it??

Comment: i tried the solution with @PostConstruct, but its not getting called..
found some circular dependency issue, (after doing some google search)

Comment: using postconstruct as suggested by javaguy , working fine now.. 
dont know what i was doing wrong earlier when i was using postconstruct as suggested by javaguy in accepted answer, and postconstruct was not getting called,,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whatever @Andreas has suggested is the best solution i.e., mark your `BaseController` as `abstract` and use `@Postconstruct`. This makes perfect scense because `BaseController` itself does not own any url mappings in your case, so do not mark it as `@Controller`

Because of any reason, if you are looking for other options, you can consider marking your `BaseController` as `@Component` and use `@Postconstruct` for `initCommonData` so that this method will be called automatically once the `BaseController` bean has been loaded by the spring container:

```
@Component
public class BaseController {

   @Autowired
   private CommonDataService commonDataService;

   protected ModelAndView model; 

    @Postconstruct
    public void initCommonData(){
       this.model = new ModelAndView();
       this.model.addObject("headerData",commonDataService.getHeaderData());
       this.model.addObject("footerData",commonDataService.getFooterData());
    }
 }
```

Comment: Remove constructor call to `initCommonData()`, and spell `@PostConstruct` correctly.

Comment: using postconstruct as suggested by you @javaguy , working fine now.. 
dont know what i was doing wrong earlier when i was using postconstruct as suggested by javaguy in accepted answer, and postconstruct was not getting called,,

Answer (score 1):

First, remove `@Controller` from your base class. You might even make the class `abstract` to help indicate/document that it must be subclassed.

Next, don't call `initCommonData()` from the constructor. Spring cannot inject field values until after the object is created, so there is no way for Spring to wire in `commonDataService` before constructor completes.

Instead, annotate `initCommonData()` with `@PostConstruct`:

```
public class BaseController {

    @Autowired
    private CommonDataService commonDataService;

    protected ModelAndView model; 

    @PostConstruct
    public void initCommonData(){
        this.model = new ModelAndView();
        this.model.addObject("headerData",commonDataService.getHeaderData());
        this.model.addObject("footerData",commonDataService.getFooterData());
    }
```

Comment: If you remove @Controller, spring can't detect the class to inject dependencies

Comment: Also, you can't make the class as abstract, because you need a singleton instance

Comment: @javaguy The class is a *base class* for other `@Controller` classes to extend, e.g. `HomeController`. It is not itself a Spring bean. See code in question.